# Trouble with updating matplotlib in realtime tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am trying to make some sort of formatter for chemical reactions using Tkinter and matplotlib. I thought It would be nice to have the chemical reaction update in realtime, but when I type too fast weird stuff happens, and it somehow types it backwards in the entry. For example, if I type "car" it would type "rac" in the entry instead. It also really laggy. I figure it has something to do with matplotlib, as when i remove the matplotlib part from the "ShowFormattedmolecule" function, it doesn't do anything weird. Any ideas why it might do this, and how do I fi it?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter as tk
import datetime
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter.ttk import *
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Kaeple")
window.geometry("300x200")

def ShowFormattedMolecule(event):
    print("Test")
    if event.char.isalpha or event.char.isdigit or event.char == "+" or event.char == "-":
        molecule = reactionEntry.get()
        plt.clf()
        plt.axis("off")
        molecule = "$\mathrm{" + molecule + "}$"
        plt.text(0.5, 0.5, molecule, ha="center", va="center", 
                              fontsize=30, fontstyle="normal", fontfamily="sans-serif")
        plt.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().update()



reactionEntry = tk.Entry()
reactionEntry.grid(column=0,row=0)
reactionEntry.bind("<Key>",ShowFormattedMolecule)

molecule = ""
figure = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
plt.axis("off")
plt.text(0.5, 0.5, molecule, ha="center", va="center", 
                        fontsize=30, fontstyle="normal", fontfamily="sans-serif")
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, window)
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1, column=1)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You know that instead of `event.char.isalpha` you should have `event.char.isalpha()`. The same goes for `event.char.isdigit`

Comment: Oh I totally forgot, that one

Comment: Also `canvas.get_tk_widget().update()` takes about 1 sec to complete on my computer so that is where your problems are coming from.